# Multiplying the integration constant

Tags: integration

If I have an integral, $\int k \frac {dy}{dx}dx$, and I take the constant k out the front, to get $k\int \frac{dy}{dx}dx$, why do I not have to multiply the +c by k once I've integrated?

So why is the answer $ky+c$ rather than $ky+kc$?

Answer (score 4):

Because $kc$ is just another constant, if you call $\tilde{c} = k c$

$$
\int k \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}{\rm d}x = k y + \tilde{c}
$$

at the end of the day you have

$$
\int k \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}{\rm d}x = k y + {\rm const}
$$

in any case, it is up to you how you want to name the constant